# Исключение: В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект

Tags: mysql, c++-cli

Не могу обратиться к строке из БД. Вылетает исключение "В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект". С чем может быть связанно?

```
try
{
  mysql_query(&mysql, query.c_str()) //отправляю запрос
  res = mysql_store_result(&mysql) //получаю результат
  row = mysql_fetch_row(res); //получаю массив строк
  UINT row_total = mysql_num_fields(res); //колличество строк 1
  System::String ^sys_row1 = gcnew System::String(row[0]); //вылетает исключение
}
catch (Exception ^e)
{
  System::String ^ex = e->Message;
  this->toolStripStatusLabel1->Text = ex;
}
```

Comment: ``row`` не пустой? ``row[0]`` не NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

да, скорее всего запрос ничего не выдовал. спасибо!